# Catch a change event on a field with no ID with jQuery

Tags: javascript, jquery

I struggle with with jQuery but need to figure this out to finish some code I'm working on.

I control the img tag but not the input (meaning I cannot give it an ID like I would like).

I need to set the img's SRC to the value of the input's value (whenever the user changes it).

Here is the HTML:

```
<div class="my_meta_control metabox">
    <img id="IconImage" src="">
    <p>
        <input type="text" class="mediafield-nn" name="_custom_meta[imgurl]" value=""/>
        <a href="media-upload.php?post_id=2&tab=type&TB_iframe=1" class="mediabutton-nn thickbox button {label:'Insert'}">Add Media</a>
    </p>
</div>
```

This is what I have been trying, with no luck.  Any help would be greatly appreciated. :)

```
$('#IconImage').next().children(":first").change(function() {
    var icon = $(this).val();
    $('#IconImage').attr('src', $(icon));
}
```

Comment: "with no luck" doesn't explain the issue. For the luck - buy horseshoe, for the *real help* - explain what you get

Comment: I'm curious: why are you having a user manually type the name of a file located on your web server? How do the users know what files are on your web server?

Answer (score 1):

Your selector is fine (though I think there are better alternatives, like `$('#IconImage').next().find("input[type='text']")`), but there are a few problems:

1. You may not be executing this code in `ready()`. I would suggest doing that.
2. You are referencing `$(icon)` instead of just `icon`. It is not a DOM selector, just text.
3. You didn't close the `(` of `.change(`.

Here is [a working JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/KpgFF/) with the above changes applied.

The code:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    $('#IconImage').next().children(":first").change(function() {
        var icon = $(this).val();
        $('#IconImage').attr('src', icon);
    });
});​
```

Comment: Thanks! It sort-of works now.  I had to change all the $ to jQuery to get it running but now it only updates the image when I put the info in there by hand and press tab.  I'm using the WordPress Media uploader and it puts the url in the field but the image doesn't update.  Any ideas?

Comment: Bam!  I got it, I was able to edit the jQuery that was doing the upload :)  Thanks again for all your help!

Comment: @user1618573 Don't forget to accept an answer if it helped you! (Just tick the checkmark next to the answer.)

Answer (score 0):

How about this:

```
var container = $('.my_meta_control metabox');

$('input:first', container).change(function(){
  $('img:first', container).attr('src', $(this).val());
});
```